# Did Adobe Premiere modify the length of the original video files?

Tags: premiere

I imported the video assets in a new Adobe Premiere project and it turns out that my video files are now having the length: `00:01:01`, which is unnatural, the modified date being the recent one (few minutes ago).

What I've done was to add the *Camera Label* and creat the multicamera sequence...

I am a bit worried that the original files were corrupted since I do not have a backup.

So far, the total folder size looks fine (`+600GB`), but I have no idea how to *reset* the video assets back to original length.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did the original clip change? Premiere doesn't alter source file.

Comment: Yes, it did... Most of the videos are now 1 minute in length...

Comment: Can you post a listing of the folder.  More information on file sizes and types and any meta data about them that you can post would be helpful.

Comment: What version of Premiere are you using? Could you please use [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) to post information about one of the source files? Premiere should not be modifying the source files at all.